# Hashes of various types of files

Tags: java, security, hash, cryptography

I need to take hashes of various types of files in an archive using java application e.g. office files, jpeg files, xmls etc.  I know I can calculate the Hashes using MessageDigest. But is there any recommendation if Hash should be taken for specific type of files only. If I have some large .swf files (flash files), is it ok to take the hash of those too? Also is there a recommended way to organize the hashes. For example if I have a zip file, and have hashes of all the files in zip file, is there a recommended way to organize i.e. tree of hashes.   Or the hash of zip file itself if good enough?

Comment: Do you need crypto or non crypto hash ?

Comment: @VictorGubin I am looking for crypto hash so that uniqueness can be guaranteed and collision resistant.

Comment: If you do not need a crypto level secure hash, then a simpler (and faster) non-crypto hash may be better.  For basic collision resistance just increase the size of the hash.  I usually suggest the [FNV](http://isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/fnv/) hash for non-crypto use: it is simple and comes in a range of sizes.

Comment: @rossum I understand non crypto hash will be faster. but my question is more about any recommendation for organizing collection of those hashes. Lets say an archive have 100 files, and I take hashes of all those 100 files, what is the best way to keep those 100 hashes.

Comment: That depends.  How often will you add/delete/modify/access the entries?  Different storage methods are better for different usage.  For example fast access to an entry may entail a lot of indexing and hence slow adding and deleting due to work on the indexes.  Does your system have a database you could use?  Otherwise have a look at the usual collection: `ArrayList`, `HashSet` etc to see which best suits the way you will be using your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a hash that is collision resistant use a Cryptographic hash. If you are trying ti create file identifiers you need a collision resistant hash.

The file type does not make a difference in the selection of a collision resistant hash.

SHA-256 is a good hash candidate for such use.

Comment: agree SHA-256 is probably best crypto hash.

Comment: SHA-512 is faster on 64 bit machines (if implemented using 64 bit instructions, of course).